# How to Delete Strings from Strings in Python

Tags: python

I am currently trying out Python. I was trying to print out an upside-down pyramid. I'm making the pyramid out of *s and in each line, I have to delete a certain amount of *s from the line. This is my

```
space = ""
astr3 = "**********"
placeholder2 = 1
while placeholder2 < 10:
    print (space, astr3, "\n")
    space += " "
    astr3 = "*********" #this is supposed to be subtraction
    placeholder2 += 1
```

Please tell if there is any way to delete strings from strings.

Comment: Please share the expected output. Not clear what you want like this,

Comment: I wanted the pyramid to look something like:
***********************
 ********************
  ******************
    **************
and so forth. I can figure out the rest of the code; I just need help with deleting the *s each line

Comment: Add the expected output in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: to delete a character from a string, set the variable to be the original string without the first character using Python's slicing notation: `astr3 = astr3[1:]`

Comment: Did you mean `*`  value will reduce by 1 per line and space value will increase by 1 per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list slicing to slice Strings/Lists. [Check it out](https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-list-slicing/). You don't need `\n` in the `print` statement as it adds a newline. To make a pyramid using your logic, you can delete two `*` from the string and then print. Remember, it's always better to use intuitive names for the variables. Eg: you can use, `idx` for index instead of `placeholder2`.

```
# Program to print an upside down pyramid
space = ""
astr3 = "**********"
num_stars = len(astr3) # len(astr3) gives number of * in the astr3 string
placeholder2 = 1
while placeholder2 < num_stars // 2:
    display_str = space + astr3 # Adding strings is called concatnation.
    print(display_str) #  This will not add additional space between spaces and astr3
    space += " "
    astr3 = astr3[:-1] # deleting the last element from the list. Called list slicing
    astr3 = astr3[1:] # deleting the first element from the list. Called list slicing
    placeholder2 += 1
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
**********
 ********
  ******
   ****
    **
```

TIP: It's better to share the expected output in the question so that the community can help.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `placeholder2` with `0` to get the pyramid from the original string to 1 length string. Since your requirements were to remove the string 1 by per line. To do it set the condition `astr3[:-1]` and put it to the same variable.

```
space = ""
astr3 = "**********"
placeholder2 = 0
while placeholder2 < 10:
    print(space, astr3)
    space += " "
    astr3 = astr3[:-1]
    placeholder2 += 1
```

**Output**

```
 **********
  *********
   ********
    *******
     ******
      *****
       ****
        ***
         **
          *
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all the help! I took what you guys said and made the pyramid :D (although my code is very very dumbed down). Here is the code:

```
space1 = ""
astr4 = "**********"
placeholder3 = 1
while placeholder3 < 7:
    if placeholder3 == 6:
        print (space1, "*")
    print(space1, astr4)
    astr4 = astr4[1:]
    astr4 = astr4[:-1]
    space1 += " "
    placeholder3 += 1
```

Comment: It produces this:
**********
  ********
   ******
    ****
     **
      *